# Simple c++ inFile and setup

Tags: c++, if-statement

The program works my only problem is that I don't know how to line up the output. When ran using the .txt file it prints the names, boxes, and name of cookies but not aligned. Also, I have to calculate the amount due for each person and display it, but i only can figure out how to do the total. Thanks for help

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

ifstream inFile;
//Declare Variables

string firstName;
string cookieName;

int boxesSold;
int numCustomers = 0;
double amountDue;
int totalCustomers;
int totalBoxesSold = 0;
double totalAmount = 0;

cout << "Girl Scout Cookies" << endl;
cout << "Created By Aaron Roberts" << endl;

inFile.open("cookie.txt");
if(inFile)
{
cout << "Customer    Number      Cookie" << endl;
cout << "Name        Of Boxes    Name" << endl;

while(inFile >>firstName>>boxesSold>>cookieName)
{
    totalBoxesSold += boxesSold;
    totalAmount += boxesSold * 3.50;

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setw(2) << firstName 
         << right << setw(7) << boxesSold
         << setw(20) << cookieName 
         << endl;
    numCustomers += 1;

}
cout << "\nNumber of Customers: "<< numCustomers << endl;
cout << "Total Boxes Sold: " << totalBoxesSold << endl;
cout << "Total Amount: $" << totalAmount << endl;
inFile.close();
}

else
{
cout << "Could not open file " << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show what the output looks like and what you'd like it to look like?  Save us some time....

Answer (score 0):

Given you've allocated 12 characters in the header for the "Customer Name" and "Number Of Boxes" columns, you probably want to allocate 11 characters for their data, leaving one character for a trailing space.

For clarity and maintainability, I recommend you create constants for these:

```
int const name_column_width = 11;
int const boxes_column_width = 11;
```

Then you can write:

```
    std::cout << std::setw(name_column_width) << std::left << "Customer" << ' '
        << std::setw(boxes_column_width) << std::left << "Number" << ' '
        << "Cookie"
        << std:: endl;

    std::cout << std::setw(name_column_width) << std::left << "Name" << ' '
        << std::setw(boxes_column_width) << std::left << "Of Boxes" << ' '
        << "Name"
        << std:: endl;

    while (inFile >> firstName >> boxesSold >> cookieName)
    {
        totalBoxesSold += boxesSold;
        totalAmount += boxesSold * 3.50;

        std::cout << std::setw(name_column_width) << std::left << firstName << ' '
            << std::setw(boxes_column_width) << std::right << boxesSold << ' '
            << cookieName 
            << std::endl;
        ++numCustomers;
    }
```

Resizing these columns then becomes a simple matter of changing the constant.